# Displaying filtered dataSet with comboBox value after loading

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, combobox

I have a Primefaces 4 DataTable with a combobox to filter its values.

How can I proceed to get the dataSet already filtered with one of its comboBox values as the user enters the webApp?

The idea is not to mix dataSet of other dates, which are in the same dataSet, since there is a summary row accordingly to the filtered data.

How can I do it?

The main xhtml code:

```
<p:dataTable 
id="datalist"
filteredValue="#{capacitacaoController.filteredCapacitacao}"
value="#{capacitacaoController.items}"
var="item"
rowKey="#{item.capacitacaoPK}"
selection="#{capacitacaoController.selected}"
>

<p:column sortBy="#{item.capacitacaoPK.dtRef}" filterBy="#{item.capacitacaoPK.dtRef}" filterOptions="#{datasController.dtRefCombo}" >
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="#{capacitacaoBundle.ListCapacitacaoTitle_capacitacaoPK_dtRef}"/>
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{item.capacitacaoPK.dtRef}">
<f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/yyyy" />
</h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

The combo method:

```
public List<SelectItem> getDtRefCombo() {
    List<SelectItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new SelectItem("I've put a date here, but no effect", "Choose..."));
    list.add(new SelectItem("Thu May 15 00:00:00 BRT 2014","05/2014"));
    list.add(new SelectItem("Tue Apr 15 00:00:00 BRT 2014","04/2014"));
    list.add(new SelectItem("Fri Feb 28 00:00:00 BRT 2014","02/2014"));
    list.add(new SelectItem("Fri Jan 31 00:00:00 BRST 2014","01/2014"));
return list;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as there is an p:column attribute for this; filterValue.

According to P. 96 in the [User guide](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_4_0_edtn2.pdf) (and Netbeans autocomplete).

Comment: Hi Jaqen H'ghar. I tried <p:column filterBy="#{item.prefDep.prefDep}" filterOptions="#{prefDepsController.depsCombo}" filterValue="9882"> where "9882" is an integer available in depsCombo. But the result is the same: when the user invoke the dataTable, the dataSet is fully loaded yet, and not filtered, as I expected. Is there something wrong? Thanks.